# Interaction between WebBrowser Control and Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I am managing various contact information - phone, address, email, IM, other and I want it to look good and save real estate, so I want to display it in a WebBrowser control. I can create the markup and content dynamically into a stream and display it with any format with colors and font size easily adjusted. I can also put buttons `<input>` for Add, Edit, and Delete. I like this method, because it seems easier and better looking than a RichTextBox (correct me if you think otherwise.)
The question is about responding to those buttons. If one is selected, I want to hide the WebBrowser and unhide a Panel with the TextBox controls needed to allow entry of a new contact or editing of an existing one. I've heard this can be done. I was hoping for suggestions. All I can think of is some code to pick up an AJAX call, that would raise a Windows event, but that seems... odd.
Any ideas, links or suggestions would be appreciated .. or even a good reason why not to do it, but it seems like a good idea for high quality information presentation and I've generated plenty of html dynamically.

Comment: You can manipulate external controls from web browser control and also you can manipulate web browser control using external controls. I believe sometimes it's better to use `WebBrowser` control instead of `RichTextBox` but I can't see an evidence here to choose web browser control. It seems, to satisfy your data entry requirements it's enough to have a `DataGridView` and some dialog boxes to add, edit and delete contact information and you don't need to create such application type.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can manipulate the `Form` and `Controls` or call C# methods from `WebBrowser` using JavaScript and also you can manipulate content of `WebBrowser` control or call JavaScript methods from C#.

#### Manipulate WinForms from Html

To manipulate your `Form` from `WebBrowser` control and call C# methods and access your form properties you should decorate your form with [`[ComVisibleAttribute(true)]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.comvisibleattribute?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) then you can set the form as [`ObjectForScripting`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.objectforscripting?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) property of `WebBrowser` control.

```
[ComVisibleAttribute(true)]
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.webBrowser1.ObjectForScripting = this;
    }
}
```

Then you can simply call methods and access to elements of your windows form this way:

**Call C# method from JavaScript:**

```
window.external.SomeCSMethod('Method called from JavaScript');
```

**Set value of a WinForms Control from JavaScript:**

Make the `textBox1` control on your `Form` to be public by setting the value of `Modifier` property to `public` using desginer. Then it can be accessible from JavaScript:

```
window.external.textBox1.Text='Value set from JavaScript';
```

#### Manipulate Html from WinForms

You can manipulate html content of web browser control from C# code and call JavaScript methods or set value of html elements using methods of [`Document`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.document?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) property of `WebBrowser`  control:

**Call JavaScript method from C#:**

```
this.webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("someJSMethod", new []{"Method called from C#"});
```

**Set value of a Html Control from C#:**

```
this.webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("text1")
                         .SetAttribute("Value set from C#", "Value From C#");
```

**Sample Code:**

You can create a `Form1` class and put `button1` and `button2` and `textBox1` and `webBrowser1` on your `Form` set the `Modifer` of `textBox1`  to public:

```
[ComVisibleAttribute(true)]
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Load += Form1_Load;
        button1.Click += button1_Click;
        button2.Click += button2_Click;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.webBrowser1.DocumentText =
        @"<html>
        <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <script>
            function someJSMethod(value){alert(value);}
        </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <input type=""text"" id=""text1""/>
            <br/>
            <input type=""button"" value=""Call C# Method"" id=""button1""
            onclick=""window.external.SomeCSMethod('Method called from JavaScript');""/>
            <br/>
            <input type=""button"" value=""Set WinForms Control Value"" id=""button2""
            onclick=""window.external.textBox1.Text='Value set from JavaScript';""/>
        </body>
        </html>";
        this.webBrowser1.ObjectForScripting = this;
    }

    public void SomeCSMethod(string value)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(value);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.webBrowser1.Document
                        .InvokeScript("someJSMethod", new[]{ "Method called from C#" });
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("text1")
                                 .SetAttribute("value", "Value set from C#");
    }
}
```

Comment: Reza, this is a fantastic explanation and example. I couldn't find anything on this. The code is complete and works perfectly ... though one must remember the modifier on the textBox. I will be using this code. Excuse me for not marking a plus on your answer, but after 10 or 15 years on Stack Exchange asking about advanced code features like this, I still have not accumulated enough reputation points to do that.