# How to send input text values from html to VB.NET

Tags: html, vb.net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I am trying to code this but I find it hard to solve it. I'll just show you the image of the scenario.

[image]

html code:

```
<tr>
    <td>Lat</td>
    <td><input type="text" size="20" id="dd_lat" value="38.898556" runat="server"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Long</td>
    <td><input type="text" size="20" id="dd_long" value="-77.037852" runat="server"></td>
</tr>
```

VB.NET code

```
Private Sub Button1_ApplyCoordinates_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1_ApplyCoordinates.Click
   Mapping.TextBox2_Latitude.Text = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("dd_lat").ToString
   Mapping.TextBox1_Longhitude.Text = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("dd_long").ToString
End Sub
```

Comment: It sounds as though you may want to look into ASP.NET.  There are a number of tutorials on http://www.asp.net/ and all over the web.  VB.NET can be used as the server-side language of an ASP.NET application, and ASP.NET WebPages uses methods with signatures similar to the one you've described.

Comment: is there an actual question? I am assuming that this is ASP.net correct?

Comment: I don't want to use asp.net I just want to pass the values from html to vb.net. The question here is, is that possible without using asp.net?

Comment: You want to enter values in a browser somewhere, but then somehow copy that into a WinForms app?  Is that your question?  If so, the answer is 'not really'.  You could host an HTML application within your VB.NET app (applications like VS Code run in this way) and that would allow you to read values from the hosted page, or I suppose you could use automation of the browser from your VB.NET app to read a value of a textbox on a web page.

Comment: The OP is using the WebBrowser winforms control based on the code in his question i.e. `... = WebBrowser1.Document...`. The tags on the question need to updated.

Comment: @ChrisDisley - I see you edited, but I've also put through an edit to resolve the mis-tagging (removed javascript, webforms, asp.net; added winforms; webbrowser-control)

Comment: @Robin No worries.  Misinterpreted the OP.  Feel free to remove/replace my edit.

Comment: [Interaction between WebBrowser Control and Windows Forms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34834774/interaction-between-webbrowser-control-and-windows-forms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ToString` method is just going to return the type of the object return by `GetElementById` and not the value of the input in the HTML. To get the latitude, or whatever, use the `GetAttribute` method and pass in "value". So your `Sub` could be coded as:

```
Private Sub Button1_ApplyCoordinates_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1_ApplyCoordinates.Click
   Mapping.TextBox2_Latitude.Text = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("dd_lat").GetAttribute("value")
   Mapping.TextBox1_Longhitude.Text = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("dd_long").GetAttribute("value")
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow, this is amazing.