# Best way to have custom listview in winforms c#

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, panel

Well I am confused, because didnt find good way to have something like `RecyclerView` in winforms.
I want to do something like this:

[image]

Its pretty easy to make it in Android but now I need same thing in Winforms for Desktop.

**What I want to see:**
ListView with Panel inside. Panel contains image and multiple labels with different sizes.

**What I tried:**

1) `ObjectListView`
Not so bad. Its smooth. But I cannot make it customize it fully. I can place simple controls inside it, but cant make multiple labels one below other.

2) `FlowLayoutPanel` and just place dynamically panels inside.
With this option I can do everything I want but after adding ~20-30 panels its not smooth anymore. Also I spend too much time for implementing "lazy loading" for it and there are really big problems with making it smooth.

So the question is: **can you recommend me better solution than I tried already?**

May be its some library or another way of using system resources.

Comment: Why a ListView at all?  A Scrolling panel with a UserControl or maybe child panels for a picturebox and a label

Comment: @Plutonix thats my second option. FlowLayoutPane with tons of panels inside it. But this option lags like hell what makes it bad decision.

Comment: Tons of __anything__ will lag in winforms. Other than that FLP with UserControls is the correct choice. To display tons of control consider WPF! - Specify 'tons', though!

Comment: I've managed to do something similar with UserControls inside a scrolling Panel as Plutonix suggested. It was actually quite smooth. I think the trick was to enable DoubleBuffering.

Comment: @Equalsk its smooth until you dont have a lot of images inside. I`m writing corporate messenger and I need this solution for chat. Imagine that user can send 20 pictures and then write wall of text. For sure I forced to use RichTextBox inside what makes it even worse -.- But DoubleBuffering is good advice anyway.

Comment: @Taw cool. Half work is done so rewriting everything for WPF is best idea ever.

Comment: No need to get sassy at me. I don't do WPF but for really big numbers, like thousands of controls it is the way to go. Hundreds should be fine in Winforms. Good luck!

Comment: The key isn't the number of controls but how many are visible. You can have thousands in a panel and the scroll can be smooth. A little advice if i may: If you dont know anything about WPF don't start learning it for this only.

Comment: You can use an HTML user interface and show it in a WebBrowser control. You can have interaction between that HTML and your Form simply. Take a look at this post: [Interaction between WebBrowser Control and Windows Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34834774/interaction-between-webbrowser-control-and-windows-forms)