# How can I pass data to/from a WebBrowser control?

Tags: c#, winforms, cookies

I've got a basic "wrapper" WinForms app which has a few basic controls and a WebBrowser control (System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser). This links to a web service which does all the actual "work" of my application.

A requirement has arisen to pass some basic data between the applications. Some of this can be achieved using the DocumentCompleted/Navigated events and using the URL property to see what page was loaded, and redirect the request elsewhere.

However, I'm struggling to work out how I can pass data that is not easily encompassed in the URL.

Is there anyway to set cookies in the request, or at least access cookies from the response?

Comment: In what direction do you want to pass the data? App to page, or page to app --  can you give an example? And, do you have control over the contents of the page?

Comment: I'm not proficient with WebBrowser control, but I think it should be possible to get the cookies on Navigated event using `webBrowser.Document.Cookie` property.

Comment: It's not clear what you are going to do, but you may find this post useful: [Interaction between WebBrowser Control and Windows Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34834774/3110834)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass and get data by calling methods from passed object as **ObjectForScripting**. 
Try this-

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public class MyScriptingClass{
    private string SomeData;
    public string GetSomeData(){
       return SomeData + " Something";
    }
    public void SetSomeData(string some){
       SomeData = some;
    }
}
```

And set **ObjectForScripting** property of your webBrowser control -

```
webBrowser.ObjectForScripting = new MyScriptingClass();
```

Now, in your javascript code call the methods like this -

```
var someVarFromJs = window.external.GetSomeData();
window.external.SetSomeData("Something to set");
```