# Need a method to capture javascript events in WinForm webbrowser control

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I have a WinForms app that uses a .NET webbrowser control. What I need to do, is wire up an event on the WinForms side to fire when a value is set (via javascript) in the loaded HTML page. I had success doing this with an onclick event of a button, but I can't seem to get it to work with a custom event. I don't know if this is a limitation in what the browser control can attach to event wise.

So essentially, I need that when a JS function is called in the HTML page and sets a value of a hidden input element (or it could be a regular input that I style to be hidden), I need to know that in WinForms. If it helps, I am using browser flags in this application to emulate IE11 instead of the default IE9 engine. The HTML page loaded is also mine so I can modify it any way needed to make this work properly. I would just use the onclick events of the buttons, but this is a gmaps integration where there can be upwards of 2000 buttons generated (one per marker placed) so it seems like a huge waste of resources to wire up 2000 onclick events when any of those button clicks only modify 4 input fields with the data I care about.

This project happens to be in VB.NET, but C# solutions would be fine as well. They can be transcoded or if the solution uses C# specific features, we can move this to a separate DLL and reference it.

Comment: [Interaction between WebBrowser Control and Windows Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34840461/3110834)

Answer (score 0):

After spending a lot of time on this today, I found a solution. It isn't a direct solution to the problem I posted, but it got me to where I needed to be. I am still interested in an answer to the original problem if anyone has one, but for now, what I found I could do was to create a class in .NET that I could assign to the ScriptingObject of the browser control and then call window.external.myFunctionName, where myFunctionName is a function within the .NET class. This works great for my specific problem, but would not work if I didn't also control the HTML page I was consuming with the browser. That is why I am still interested in alternate solutions if anyone has one. Thanks.