# how to match scrollbar to lines in RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, scrollbar, richtextbox

I'm adding buttons (with text and images) to a `richtextbox` control, but because I don't use the following line:

```
richTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + str);
```

The scroll bar doesn't match the total number of lines, and doesn't resize properly, how can I solve it?

Comment: Winform or Wpf?

Comment: @Mark im using winform

Comment: So that we are both on the same page, are you saying that the scrollbar doesn't update properly when content is added to the richtextbox? Also, how are you adding content to the richtextbox?

Comment: yes for the first part, and I add content (buttons) like that: richTextBox1.Controls.Add(button);

Comment: What's your original requirement? Buttons, text and images looks like HTML content. Do you know you can use a `WebBrowser` control to show HTML content in windows forms and you can have [interaxtion between WebBrowser control and Form](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34840461/3110834)?

Answer (score 0):

## What is going wrong

I find this to be a very peculiar way of doing things. So first, lets add a little background:

When you use `richTextBox1.Controls.Add(new button())` - what you are doing is: you are adding the new button as a *child* of the `richtextbox`, not as content - and this is the problem.

The scrollbars are set to read their height/scrollable area etc from the content of the `richtextbox`, and yours has no content, hence no scrollbar (or false readings etc).

You could create a custom richtextbox control that inherits its scrollable area from the location of its child controls. However, if you would rather avoid that route, please continue reading:

## The correct way

I do not know your use case, so this may not work, but I would remove the `richtextbox` control and instead use a `panel` control. The panel control for example will update it's scrollbars based on child controls, whereas the `richtextbox` wont - and this should give you the behaviour you are expecting.

Comment: thanks, I did switched to panel instead of richtextbox (and it worked), it was better for me before but not anymore.