# Winform webBrowser's event don't fire

Tags: c#

I have the function to open a YouTube video and control them. it work fine on internet browser but the events, onPlayerReady and onPlayerStateChange, dont fire on web browser control. I'm using c# windows application.
Any help please?

```
    webBrowser.ObjectForScripting = this;
    int w = workingArea.Width - 40;
    int h = workingArea.Height - 20;
    this.brwYoutubePlayer.Width = w + 2;
    this.brwYoutubePlayer.Height = h + 2;

    string VIDEO_ID = url.Substring(0, url.IndexOf("?"));
    VIDEO_ID = VIDEO_ID.Substring(VIDEO_ID.LastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    var embed = "<html><head>" +
    "<meta http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\" content=\"IE=Edge\"/>" +
     "<body scroll=\"no\" style=\"padding:0px;margin:0px;\">" +
     " <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.youtube.com/player_api'></script>" +
     " <iframe id=\"myPlayer\" width=\"{1}\" height=\"{2}\" src=\"{0}\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>" +
    "<script type =\"text/javascript\">" +
    " var player; function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady(){{window.external.Test('Video start!!');" +
    " player = new YT.Player('myPlayer',{{" +
    " videoId : '" + VIDEO_ID + "'," +
    " events : {{'onReady' : onPlayerReady, 'onStateChange' : onPlayerStateChange}}}});}}"+
    "function onPlayerReady() {{window.external.Test('onPlayerReady'); }}" +
    " function onPlayerStateChange(evt){{window.external.Test('chenge status!!'); " +
    " if(evt.data==0){{ window.external.Test('Video finished!!');}}}}" +
    "</script>" +
    "</body></html>";
    webBrowser.DocumentText = string.Format(embed, url, w, h);
```

Comment: follow this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34840461/6797509

Comment: Hi, my problem is with event that is not been fired. For exemple the function onPlayerReady() is not called when the video is ready either the function onPlayerStateChange(evt) don't respond when the video start or paused or for any state change at all.

Comment: did you try `InvokeScript` method ?!

Comment: I am using InvokeScript to call javaSript function like weBrowser.Document.InvokeScript("Mute", null); but even this function is give a error Unable to get property mute of undefined or null reference.  I need get control to the video, to now when it finish, pause or mute and time.